# Editor in custom code doesn't work

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I've inherited some custom code running in Joomla 3.0.2 - we it's actually some standalone php/javascript that's run using Sourcerer (ie not a proper component).

I need it to display an rich-text editor, so I'm trying to use the standard editors which come with joomla. I've written some PHP based on [this tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_editor_in_a_component):

```
    $document =& JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addScript('includes/js/joomla.javascript.js');

    $editor =& JFactory::getEditor();
    echo $editor->display('content', 'some content', '550', '400', '60', '20', false);
```

However all I get is a standard textarea without the toolbars. I've tried setting all pre-installed editors (CodeMirror, TinyMCE) to the default editor, plus I've tried the JCE and JoomlaCK plugins - all with the same result.

I guess the problem is that the code example is for an older version of Joomla, as includes/js/joomla.javascript.js doesn't exist. But I can't find an updated example anywhere... please help!

Comment: One thing for sure is don't use the & in PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript(JURI::root() . 'includes/js/joomla.javascript.js');

$editor = JFactory::getEditor();
echo $editor->display('content', 'some content', '550', '400', '60', '20', false);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work either. The file literally isn't there in Joomla 3 - I assume it's either been moved since 2.5 or that it no longer exists and there's a new way of doing this.